# Power SW button doesn't work

Tags: motherboard, front-panel

Yesterday I built a computer myself. The computer is able to boot by pressing the power button on the mobo. However, the Power Button on the case isn't working. Everything is setup by following the manual from the mobo and the case.

> Specs: Motherboard: Gigabyte Z98X-UD3H
>
> Case: Sharkoon T28

I tried to connect the Power SW upside down but that doesn't solve the problem. I've also read that polarity doesn't matter on Power SW. Some other front panel connections are working: Power LEDS and Reset Switch.

Comment: Try connecting the reset switch in place of the power switch and see if it works, it may just be a faulty switch.

Comment: @zelanix that will do no harm to anything?

Comment: no, they are both just normal contact switches. That's why you can connect the power sw upside down - all it does is make a connection when you press the switch.

Comment: @zelanix alright, I'll try it as soon as I get home. Thanks

Comment: Switches aren't some ultra-advanced electrical components. They just make contact between two leads when pressed, it's purely mechanical. It doesn't matter if you connect the first pin with the second one or the second one with the first one, it's all the same. It also doesn't matter how you connect them - with a switch, jumper, a piece of wire or a metal screwdriver. They are connected or they are not, it's really that simple.

Comment: @gronostaj ah that makes sense.

Comment: @zelanix Your suggestion worked. The Power SW cable appeared to be broken, it's fixed now. Thanks.